# How the flow of code in while loop going in android?

Tags: android, while-loop, try-catch

I am new in Android (Java) coding . I have a small game program downloaded. In that to terminate the thread , have the code

```
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    boolean retry = true;
    while (retry) {
        try {
            thread.setRunning(false);
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        retry = false;
    }
}
```

Here the code author says if catch the exception , the code will go to try   part not to the statement retry = false;
I could not believe that. please advise the flow is correct.

[image: program flow]

Please advise

Thanks

Anes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop will be run once. No matter if an Exception is thrown since retry will always be set to false after the first run. If you wanted the loop to continue until no Exception is thrown, you could place the `retry = false;` directly after the `thread.join();` in the try block so it's only being called when you don't get to the catch block.